# Corona SDK, build for iOS device works not correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sdk, coronasdk

I build my Corona app for iPhone Simulator, and it running well. But if I installed my app on my device(iPad), and i have many issues(no scrollview and tabbar working) buttons is visible only.
How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what happens when you run it in the iPad simulator- Do you get any errors in the console if you check it while running the app on your iPad? If so this could shed some light on the issue. One possibility is a corrupted image, or an incorrect image format.

If only the buttons are visible it sounds like you app has an error that is preventing all of the display objects from loading. (Just based on the fact you mention your buttons display but nothing else.)

Comment: I don't understand what console did you mean?

Comment: Open Xcode with your device connected and go to "Organizer" using the menu or by using the shortcut CMD+Shift+2, click your device in the left and under it will be "console". This will provide you with additional details.